# creating new page when the user click on add page button in android studio application

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm trying to code a story application (android studio using java), where a child can use an electronic book to write his stories.

now, I want to write story pages code (which is in an image view) open book image[image: open book image]but I don't know how to do it?
Im planning to use fragments, but how can I do that: when a child click on add new page button; a new page created?

Thank you